# total number of nodes in xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to get the total number of nodes in an xml file 
for Elements we use
 `NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");`
but for nodes if you have any idea 
Thank you

Comment: It might be better to be a bit more explicit about exactly which nodes you want to count. Attributes? Namespaces? Whitespace text nodes? Entity and CDATA nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The code below might work. 
The idea is to count each element of an XML file (and also its child elements), using recursion.

```
public class Main {

    int totalNodes = 0;

    public Main() throws Exception {
        String file = getClass().getResource("/test.xml").getFile();
        File fXmlFile = new File(file);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        countNodes(doc.getDocumentElement());
        System.out.println(totalNodes);
    }

    public void countNodes(Node node) {
        System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
        totalNodes++;
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {                    
                countNodes(currentNode);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't count attribute nodes. Which might or might not be what was intended.

Comment: your code is the equivalent to this function :     int N = doc.getElementsByTagName("*").getLength()

Comment: @MichaelKay , changing a bit the code might work for other types of nodes such as attributes nodes. Using Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE in the if clause might work as you expect.

Comment: @ThiagoProcaci I don't have any expectations. I'm merely pointing out that the requirements are unclear, and in that situation, it's best not to write any code until they are clarified.